# Asynchronous DAO in Flex / Sqlite?

Tags: sql, apache-flex, sqlite, dao

[The article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/flex/articles/sqlite_db_api_in_air.html) gives a good insight of how to deal with sqlite in Flex; but it doesn't get deep into how to tackle asynchronous data access.

For example, if I have an EmployeesDAO that does the followings:

- updateEmployee(emp:Employee):void
- findEmployee(emp:Employee):void
- findAllEmployees():ICollectionView

etc..

As long as the EmployeesDAO implements asynchronous mode these methods are only legitimate after the db is connected and the tables are created. The client has to know about this asynchronous nature in order to use these methods as the following will throw an SQLErrorOperation as findAllEmployees will attempt to execute a "SELECT" operation before the db is connected:

```
var dao:IEmployeesDAO = new EmployeesDAO();
var employees:ArrayCollection = dao.findAllEmployees();
```

What is the best practice to deal with instantiation of the asynchronous DAO? Is it possible to hide the asynchronous nature from the client of the data access objects (i.e., the client isn't aware whether it's using sync or asynchronous DAOs)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know to tackle a problem like that is to use pass the results to a callback. That's how we tackled listening to various async tokens or event messages.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking is not possible in the flash universe to my knowledge.  In JS I know of only one project that effectively tackles this problem.

http://stratifiedjs.org tries to be javascript-like language with just some extra keywords to decide what you want to do in asynchronous situations and compiles to not-so-readeable but very performant JS behind the scenes.

Comment: I'm sure "some day" SJS will be ported to Flash ;)

Comment: I do hope so! :) What can also make asynchronous things a bit more sane in flex is Mate.  Here's an article on using Mate with air sqlite : http://goo.gl/vFLyB

Answer (score 0):

Have a look: http://elromdesign.com/blog/2009/01/18/adobe-air-sqlite-manager-help-you-handle-your-database-easily/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Does it seem to only deal with the synchronous mode or did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0):

There is a fundamental difference between asynchronous and sync programming and the client code has to be aware of that to use the service. The pattern for dealing with asynchronous database connectivity is to have the client pass callbacks to a specific operation invocation to handle the result (if successful) or fault (if operation failed). The callbacks can be encapsulated in things such as [flash.net.Responder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Responder.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2) or [mx.rpc.IResponder](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/IResponder.html), etc.. In a LOB application, the life-cycle of the app is tied to the DB connectivity such that the moment the app attempts to start, DB connection has to either already be established (such as user being authenticated) or otherwise the UI locks the user out. After the DB connection has been established, all the DAO instances can get hold of the DB connection. Of course the subsequent operations on the DB still need to implement the callback patterns mentioned above.